# Possible mistake in Specker's thesis

Tags: set-theory

From [Specker's thesis "Zur Axiomatik der Mengenlehre (Fundierungs- und Auswahlaxiom)"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/malq.19570031302/abstract):

Take $A$ to be a countable infinite set of atoms, $G$ the group of all permutations of the universe $\mathcal P^\infty (A) $ that fix all but a finite number of atoms and let $F$ be the filter of subgroups generated by subgroups that fix a finite number of atoms. On page 198 you can find claim (2): There is no injection $A \times A \to \mathcal P (A)$. Note that in the paper he uses $a$ to denote the set of atoms, $g$ to denote the group, $e$ to denote a finite subset of $a$, $h(e)$ to denote the subgroup of $g$ that fixes $e$ and $J$ to denote the filter.

My question is about his proof. Here is the original:

[image]

If I understand correctly, $H^\ast$ is $H$ restricted to $a \setminus e$. Consider the following sentence: "Note that $H^\ast$ is mapped to itself by automorphisms that correspond to transpositions of two elements of $a \setminus e$: The sets to which $H^\ast$ maps pairs in $a \setminus e \times a \setminus e$  contain the same elements of $e$".

I don't believe that $H^\ast$ is mapped to itself. Consider the following counter example: $((a,b), \{s\}), ((a',b), \{s'\}) \in H^\ast$ under the transposition that swaps $a$ and $a'$. If both images, $((a',b), \{s\}), ((a,b), \{s'\}) $ were in $H^\ast$ it would be a contradiction to the assumption that $H$ is injective.

Hence my question: which bit of his argument am I misunderstanding? Thanks for your help in advance.

---

Edit: Here is 2.61 with the definition of $e$:

[image]

Comment: As I read it, $e$ is a fixed finite subset of $a$ determined ‘as in $2.61$’; how was $e$ determined in $2.61$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott "...$e$ eine endliche Teilmenge von $a$...". Or would it be better if I also copy pasted that part?

Comment: It probably would.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Done.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott $h$ is assumed to map $H$ to itself. But I don't see how it follows for all transpositions of $a^\ast$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If he’s doing what Felgner does in the only presentation of this material that I’ve seen, he’s assuming that $H\in\mathfrak{M}[G,F]$, which means that $\{\varphi\in G:\varphi[H]=H\}\in F$ and hence that there is a finite $e\subseteq a$ such that $h=h(e)\le\{\varphi\in G:\varphi[H]=H\}$. Thus, if $\varphi$ is a permutation interchanging two elements of $a^*$, then $\varphi\in h$, and $\varphi[H]=H$. If these assumptions are present in the background of $2.62$, then your example is excluded by hypothesis.

Comment: @Matt: You’re welcome.

Comment: Do you mean Felgner in the "Models of ZF set theory" book?

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, Yellow Peril #$223$.